# Style a variable output in return of a controller method

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm returning a success message on payment completion in a controller method return. And also concatenating a variable that I received from request to display along with it.

How do I style this variable? Like make it a bit bold or something like that.

I'm returning this:

```
return back()->with('success_message', 'Thank you! Your payment has been accepted. This is the link you bought: '. $request->title;
```

I'm showing message in blade like this

```
@if (session()->has('success_message'))  
      <div class="alert alert-success">
          {{ session()->get('success_message') }}  
      </div>
@endif
```

I want to style `$return->title`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return an array of messages

```
return back()->with([
    'success_message' => 'Thank you! Your payment has been accepted. This is the link you bought: ',
    'title' => $request->title
]);
```

and in style it accordingly in your view

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    {{ session()->get('success_message') }}
    <strong>{{ session()->get('title') }}</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$parameters = ['success' => 'Thank you! Your payment has been accepted. This is the link you bought: ', 'title' => $request->title];
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with($parameters);
```

**OR**

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withFlashSuccess($parameters);
```